# List<DateTime?> Always Adding Only One Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to allow user to select a date and press add button on which the date should be
added to a list, it adds the selected date, but if user wants to add another date
the previous one is disappeared here is my code

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<DateTime?> Holidays = new List<DateTime?>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtOthrHoliday.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }

    protected void btnAddHoliday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOthrHoliday.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            Holidays.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(txtOthrHoliday.Text,extOtherHoliday.Format, null));
        }
  }
```

So when I add another button to check Holidays.Count() it will return me 0, I have tried setting the list as static but no success

Comment: which control it is `txtOthrHoliday`?

Comment: its a text box with CalendarExtender user selects a date, and presses Add button, it does add one date to the list, but when user presses Add after selecting a 2nd date, I get only one date i.e. latest in my Holidays list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep `List<DateTime?> Holidays` in Session or some whwere to maintain it's state.

You can also keep it into `ViewState` duration postback.

Similar Question on SO

1. [Maintain generic list between postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710277/maintain-generic-list-between-postbacks)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is each time user select date your page gets posted(in other words re-rendered) and your `Holidays` object gets initialized again, simple solution is keep your `Holidays` object in `ViewState`(ViewState values are not carried between pages)

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<DateTime?> Holidays;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ViewState["Holidays"] != null)
            Holidays = ViewState["Holidays"] as List<DateTime?>;
        else
            Holidays = new List<DateTime?>();
    }

    protected void btnAddHoliday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOthrHoliday.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            Holidays.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(txtOthrHoliday.Text,extOtherHoliday.Format, null));
            ViewState["Holidays"] = Holidays;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using static works for me, I would use the ViewState or Session
if I need to reset the list which is not yet needed in the application